# ng-repeat only objects with specific property value - custom filter?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

So say I have a JSON object 'user' with some basic properties like: 'name', 'address', 'role', etc.

I want the ng-repeat to only spit out the objects in which the property 'role' equates to 'administrator'. How would I go about doing that?

I'm thinking something like a custom filter, or possibly making a scope variable where I put the matching objects in an array, and then repeat through them.

What is the best practice for this case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The built in [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) can handle this case...

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users | filter : {role: 'administrator'} : true">
   ...
</div>
```

Comment: Quick question: this works fine for top-level properties, but my user case requires me to filter by a property that is one level down. $scope.user = User.get(); $scope.user.role.name; is the property I need to filter by.

Comment: It'd take slightly more work but you should be able to pass a predicate function into the filter to apply any custom logic you need. For example: `function (value) { return value.role.name === "administrator"; }`