# Angular 1: filter ng-repeat output depending on object property

Tags: angularjs

I have simple ng-repeat in my view that prints data from objects.

```
  <div
    ng-repeat="item in toDoItems |
               orderBy: 'createdAt'
               track by item.createdAt"
  >
    <b>Content:</b> {{item.content}}
  </div>
```

The object that I am printing looks like this:

```
     {
        "content" : "some content",
        "createdAt" : "1459401001460",
        "completed" : false
      },
      {
        "content" : "some content",
        "createdAt" : "1459401001325",
        "completed" : true
       }
```

I only want to print items that have value `false` in `"completed"` propery.

I have tried this but it would give me error: [ng-repeat only objects with specific property value - custom filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24473001/ng-repeat-only-objects-with-specific-property-value-custom-filter)

Comment: just use `ng-show` :) below is my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this format of filter.

```js
var myapp = angular.module('app', []);
myapp.controller('Main', function ($scope) {
  $scope.data =[
       {
         "content" : "some content",
         "createdAt" : "1459401001460",
         "completed" : false
       },
      {
         "content" : "some content",
         "createdAt" : "1459401001325",
         "completed" : true
       },
       {
         "content" : "some content2",
         "createdAt" : "1459401001460",
         "completed" : false
       },
      {
         "content" : "some content",
         "createdAt" : "1459401001325",
         "completed" : true
       },
       {
         "content" : "some content3",
         "createdAt" : "1459401001460",
         "completed" : false
       },
      {
         "content" : "some content",
         "createdAt" : "1459401001325",
         "completed" : true
       }
 ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app = "app">
  <div ng-controller="Main">

<div >
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr ng-repeat="d in data | filter: {completed: false }">
            <td>{{d.content}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this custom filter

```
app.filter('myFilter', function () {
    return function (items) {
        if (!items) {
            return true;
        }
        if (items.length == 0) {
            return items;
        }
        var newItems = [];
        angular.forEach(items, function(item, index){
           if(item.completed==true || item.completed=='true'){
               newItems.push(item)
           }
        })
        return newItems ;
    };
});
```

And your HTML is:

```
 <div ng-repeat="item in toDoItems | myFilter track by $index">
        <b>Content:</b> {{item.content}}
  </div>
```

Comment: May I ask you what is a good place to put custom filter files?

Comment: I worked lot on performance of the application. On **Dev environment** it doesn't matter where you place all JS files and how many files you create. I generally place all filters in separate files at module level. But on **production environment** try to minimize the HTTP requests. For that you have to minify JS code and place all your JS code into 2-3 files maximum.

Answer (score 0):

```
<b ng-show='item.completed==false'>Content:</b> 
<span ng-show='item.completed==false'>{{item.content}}</span>
```

Comment: yes it can be, you have to create a custom `filter` for that and you are done

Answer (score 0):

Use [angular filter plugin](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#filterby) for this, Change your code like below

Inject

```
<div
        ng-repeat="item in toDoItems | filterBy: ['completed']: true |
                   orderBy: 'createdAt'
                   track by item.createdAt"
      >
        <b>Content:</b> {{item.content}}
      </div>
```